# How to use "IN" with "CASE Statement" in WHERE Clause?

Tags: mysql, wildcard, where-clause, case-statement

Below is my MYSQL Query

```
select * from `ordermaster` where OrderStatus in (case when 1= 0 then OrderStatus else ("Completed","Cancelled") end)
```

as you can see 1st condition is ALL and next condition is Specific.

if condition 1 is satisfied then I would like to return entire data w.r.t orderstatus but if condition is satisfied then I want only records whose OrderStatus is "Completed" OR "Cancelled" but this is giving issue. I can directly use "IN" but cannot use with "CASE" statement.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Can you give a sample of data and expected output just to clarify your needs?

Comment: Hi I'm not concerned about data and also its not about data. It's just syntax. see if condition 1 is satisfied then i will like to return entire data w.r.t orderstatus but if condition is false/2nd then I want only records whose OrderStatus is "Completed" OR "Cancelled".

Comment: Ok, what is the `condition 1`, because I only see this `when 1 = 0` and that condition is ever `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ordermaster
    CASE 
        WHEN OrderStatus = 1 THEN 'Completed'
        WHEN OrderStatus = 0 THEN 'Cancelled'
    END AS STATUS 
FROM ordermaster;
```